# How do different parameters affect Big O Notation for time complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, runtime, big-o, computer-science

For example, if I have two parameters M and N inside my method and the time complexity turns out to be O(M+N), why do people say O(M+N) instead of O(N), which is simplified from O(2N)? When should we use multiple variables in our Big O Notation? Is there any reasoning behind it? How would different variables passed in for arguments affect the growth rate, why not combine them into one variable for big O? I cannot think of an instance of where different variables parameters passed in can affect run time. Just got into data structures and algorithms, so was wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Time complexity represents how the runtime changes w.r.t the change in the input size.

The 2 variables passed to the method represent the size of the input and they both are 2 different dimensions.

If `M >>> N`, then `O(M + N)` is equivalent to `O(M)` and if `N >>> M`, then `O(M + N)` is equivalent to `O(N)`.

We can combine `M` and `N` only when `M ~ N`, i.e., time complexity = `O(2*N)` or `O(2*M)` which is equivalent to `O(N)` or `O(M)`.

Otherwise `O(M + N)` is a precise way to represent the time complexity that takes care of all the above mentioned 3 cases on constraints of `M` and `N`.

Comment: So since in this case we are having an input size of two different variables that can represent two different sizes, we cannot combine them to be O(2N), hence why it must be O(M+N)?

Comment: @plsdontbeangry Yes

Comment: Could the two variables be causing different effects on the growth rates for time complexity, for it to be another reason for us to do O(M+N)? M could have a larger growth rate than N, making us do O(M+N), or is that not a factor for why it is like that?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly speaking, big O notations are kind of approximations. Because **O(N*N + N)** is considered as **O(N*N)**. However it is a standard rule that overall big O notation of an algorithm is equivalent to its slowest part.

*example*

if an algo is of O(N + logN) complexity then it has to be written as O(N) complexity.